# Group same numbers in a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to group a list of number in python?

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
list = [0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

And I want to group the same number in the same list.

My expected output is like this:

```
list = [0, 7, 4, 2, 1]
```

I know this is really simple. I tried googling but I can't find any solution for what I really looking for.

Comment: You are not grouping the list. ```[0, 7, 4, 2, 1]``` -  you are removing the duplicates which can be achieved with ```list(set([0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1]))```. Also please avoid using ```in-built``` functions like ```list``` as variables

Comment: read about `set`

Comment: What is the expected output on this: `[0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7]`? Because if you want it to output `0,7,4,2,1,7` then you can't simply remove the duplicates

Comment: But you should know that `set` doesn't preserve order of elements.

Comment: @OlvinRoght then ```list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1]))```

Comment: @Sujay, starting from python 3.7 `dict` and `OrderedDict` are same, so `list(dict.fromkeys([0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1]))`

Comment: @Sujay How do you know they want to turn `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]` into `[1, 2]` instead of `[1, 2, 1]`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Not really same, but same for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your word usage of "group" I am guessing you want something more than to just remove the duplicates. Here is how you group numbers together and preserve their order:

```
def group_same_nums(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []

    new_lst = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] != new_lst[len(new_lst)-1]:
            new_lst.append(lst[i])
            
    return new_lst
```

Usage:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7]
lst = group_same_nums(lst)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 7, 4, 2, 1, 7]
```

But in the case you want to simply remove the duplicates you can use the method that Sujay and Olvin Roght pointed out in their comments:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7]
lst = list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 7, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing the duplicates is what I really want.  But maybe I can also use the grouping in the future. Thanks for all the comments and answer. This is my first time posting a question and I'm so glad that stackoverflow is this active. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You did mention *groups*, so here is a solution with grouping:

```
import itertools

lst = [0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1]  # do not use list as a name
glst = [g for g, _ in itertools.groupby(lst)] # [0, 7, 4, 2, 1]
```

Docs: [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> It generates a break or new group every time the value ... change